# How to put the result of a for Statement into a table?

Tags: java, postgresql, for-loop

What's the best way to put the result of a `for` Statement into a `PostgreSQL` table?

Example:

```
int size = 5;
try {
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
            ??? x = (i * j); 

            String sql = "INSERT INTO multiplication" +
                         "VALUES (???)";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you created a table in the database? What is its structure (show the CREATE TABLE statement)?

Comment: The CREATE TABLE statement in not on this code, but the table is already created... I also tested the connection and did a simple INSERT like "INSERT INTO multiplication VALUES (3, 6, 9, 12, 15)" and it worked just fine.

Comment: Question reworded to fit the rules and help others users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use prepared statements:

```
int size = 5;
String strSQL = "insert into multiplication values (?)"; 
/* 
 * I am assuming your table has only one column.
 * If it has more columns, you need to specify the column where you want 
 * to insert the value:
 *     "insert into multiplication (col1) values (?)"
 *
 * The question mark is a place-holder for the value you are about to insert.
 *
 * I am also assuming that you have a Connection object named "conn".
 */
try(PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(strSQL)) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
            /*
             * You are multiplying integers, so the result is also an integer
             */
            int x = i * j;
            /*
             * Assign the value to the prepared statement
             */
            ps.setInt(1, x);
            ps.execute(); // The statement is executed HERE
        }
    }
} catch(SQLException e) {
    // Exception handling code
}
```

Prepared statements have some advantages:

1. You can write the SQL instruction only once, and use it many times. You just need to enter the index of the place holder (starting with 1) and assign the appropriate value. There are `setXXX()` methods for most SQL data types (and `setNull()` methods if there's the need for them).
2. Prepared statements help in preventing [SQL injection attacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) ((for a funny example of what are the risks of SQL injection attacks, check [xkcd: Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)).
3. If you have a large number of instructions, you can execute them in a batch.

**Batch example:**

```
int size = 5;
String strSQL = "insert into multiplication values (?)"; 
try(PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(strSQL)) {
     for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
         for(int j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
             int x = i * j;
             ps.setInt(1, x);
             ps.addBatch(); // The statement is added to the batch (but not executed yet)
         }
     }
     ps.executeBatch(); // All the instructions in the batch are executed HERE
 } catch(SQLException e) {
     // Exception handling code
 }
```

---

**References:**

- [The Java Tutorials: JDBC - Prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
- [Java API: `PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: In case size^2 generates a high number of operations e.g. size = 100 which will generate 10k inserts, you may want to insert these in batch instead.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza note taken... updating the post to include this alternative

Comment: Thanks for your help! My table has five columns and I will specify them so it can insert the values correctly.

Comment: @Happy to help. I recommend you take a good read of the JDBC tutorial, and also of the PostgreSQL reference on the topic (for any specific "tricks")

Answer (score 0):

You might try this.

```
int size = 5; 
try {
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
            String x = String.valueOf(i * j); 

            String sql = "INSERT INTO multiplication" +
                     "VALUES (" + x + ")";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ***Warning!*** Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: You might try to use `PreparedStatement` when sending parameters to your queries when using JDBC.

Comment: (for a funny example of what are the risks of SQL injection attacks, check [xkcd: Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/))

Comment: yes, i know... i just wanted to suggest a quick fix... i agree that the use of preparedstatements is much preferable...